# Why does VSCode debugger generate an incomplete command in the terminal and fail to launch?

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm seeing some strange behavior trying to debug a Node.js app in VSCode.

- When I select a configuration to run and debug, it generates some code at the command line in the integrated terminal.
- However, the code gets clipped, so that the command is incomplete.  The amount of clipping seemed to be related to the PATHs i was exporting in my `~/.zshrc` file.
- It seems to generate the correct command when I remove all PATH exports in my `.zshrc` file, however, it does not automatically run - it waits, uncompleted, until i click into the line and hit enter.  It then runs.
- And after I do that the first time, it will then run correctly without requiring the user (me) to click in and hit enter)
- When I do, it seems to run it twice - it outputs the same text twice, the first terminated by a `%`, and then a new line is started where the same text is generated.

Script that is generated:

```sh
/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.pyenv/shims:/Users/USERNAME/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands' 'NODE_OPTIONS=--require "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js" --inspect-publish-uid=http' 'VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS={"inspectorIpc":"/var/folders/tv/3png1fgn2071ql5yd6n2rjgw0000gn/T/node-cdp.3142-1.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"/Users/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/node","onlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallback":"/var/folders/tv/3png1fgn2071ql5yd6n2rjgw0000gn/T/node-debug-callback-0ecc30434e46d30d"}' /Users/USERNAME/FOLDER/PROJECT/REPO/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js --nolazy .
```

(i have renamed items that are listed in CAPS)

Note this happens in different repos that are using various versions of Node, not just the one listed by the command line output (ie: v14.17.1)

In trying to troubleshoot, I've completely removed or uninstalled (and reinstalled) VSCode, Node, NVM, `PATH` exports from my `.zshrc` file, but it's still happening.  Unclear where to go from here.

**edit:**
this looks related to posts on VSCode debugger not launching or attaching, but haven't found anything that resolves the issue yet.

- [VSCode debugging C++ launches external terminal, but doesn't run program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946631/vscode-debugging-c-launches-external-terminal-but-doesnt-run-program)

**edit2:**
i could swear I'm running up against the maximum limit of input in my terminal (MacOS 11.6, zsh).  i understand this is determined by the operating system and not the shell you're using.

- https://serverfault.com/questions/69430/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-command-line-in-mac-os-x
- https://serverfault.com/questions/69430/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-command-line-in-mac-os-x

my `ARG_MAX` looks huge though:

```
> ~ getconf ARG_MAX
1048576
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was because of the length of the value for my `PATH` variable, and it was running into the max limit for MacOS.  After trying a number of things, this was finally resolved after I changed how i was adding things to `PATH`.

I could see my clipped terminal invocation for my VSCode debugger was consistently at or around 1024 characters with the following exports to `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH" # moved to .profile
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

I updated it to this, which brings my invoked VSCode terminal debugger invocation to around 800 characters.

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$(getconf PATH)"
```

Comment: I see I'm setting `PATH` rather than exporting it - i haven't looked into that, but have not had a problem since then.  More details about that at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138504